# Solutions X Y Z

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One ounce of solution X contains only ingredients a and b in a ratio of 2 : 3. One ounce of solution Y contains only ingredients a and b in a ratio of 1 : 2. If solution Z is created by mixing solutions X and Y in a ratio of 3 : 11, then 630 ounces of solution Z contains how many ounces of a?

(A) 68, (B) 73, (C) 89, (D) 219, (E) 236

Please help me solve this, I'm stuck at first step.

Comment: For a first step.  How would you divide 630 in a ratio of 3:11.  Or before that, if something is divided in a ratio of 3:11, what fraction of it is the small part and what fraction is the large part?  (Imagine a pie cut into equal parts, 3 of one color and 11 of another, but all equal)

Comment: 630 / 11=57.27272727... That's not a whole number but is this still okay?

Comment: No.  you wouldn't divide 630 by 11.  Just one more question, because I'm mean.  What if 630 were divided in a ratio of 1:1?  What would you do.

Comment: 315 : 315 which has 315+315=630?

Comment: Correct.  If they are in ratio of a:b, then the first part is $\frac{a}{a+b}$ and the second part is $\frac{b}{a+b}$. So in your case, the small part (Think back to the pie) is $\frac{3}{14}$ and the large part is $\frac{11}{14}$.  You would multiply each of those fractions by 630 to get how much there is of each.

Comment: So when 630 divided in a ratio of 3 : 11, I will get 135 : 495. Now how can I use the other given ratios 2 : 3 and 1 : 2?

Comment: Use the same basic idea.  $\frac{2}{2+3}$ and $\frac{3}{2+3}$ etc...

Comment: In solution Y, the ratio 1 : 2 gives 1/3 of a and 2/3 of b. In solution X, the ratio 2 : 3 gives 2/5 of a and 3/5 of b. Then mixing solutions X and Y to create Z, do I apply these fractions o 3/14 and 11/14 in some way?

Comment: You are done with 3:11 at this point. Ill add an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  So you used $\frac{3}{3+11}$ and $\frac{11}{3+11}$ to deduce that you're dealing with 135 of Solution X and 495 of Solution Y.

Then you look at them individually.  $\frac{2}{5}$ of Solution X is type $a$ and $\frac{3}{5}$ of Solution X is type $b$.  Or $\frac{2}{5}\times135$ is $a$ and $\frac{3}{5}\times135$ is $b$

Similarly:  $\frac{1}{3}$ of Solution Y is type $a$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ of Solution Y is type $b$.  Or $\frac{1}{3}\times495$ is $a$ and $\frac{2}{3}\times495$ is $b$.

Add up those two values of $a$ and hopefully you get 219.

Comment: So the ratio 3 : 11, divides the 630 ounces of Solution Z into 135 ounces of Solution X and 435 ounces of Solution Y. Then we decompose Solution X further into Ingredients a and b using the ratio 2 : 3. Same with Solution Y using the ratio 1 : 2. The question asks only for ingredient a: Solution X will give 54 ounces of a and Solution Y will give 165 ounces of ingredient a. In total, we have 219 ounces (choice d) present in Solution Z. In summary it was really decomposing Solution Z into Solutions X and Y, and in turn decomposing each of them into ingredients a and b using ratios!

Comment: Yes.  Good summary.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very basic, nonetheless, here's the answer:

For solution $Z$, the ratio of $X$ and $Y$ is $3:11$

$X$ : $Y$ = $3:11$

Which means, in 14 parts of solution $Z$, $X$ will be 3 parts and $Y$ will be 11 parts.

So, in 630 ounces of solution $Z$, $X$ will be = $\frac {630\times 3}{14} = 135$ Ounce.

And $Y$ will be = $\frac {630\times 11}{14} = 495$ Ounce.

Volume of $a$ in $Z$ = {volume of $a$ in $X$ $+$ volume of $a$ in $Y$}

Volume of $a$ in $X$ = $135 \times \frac {2}{5} = 54$

Volume of $a$ in $Y$ = $495 \times \frac {1}{3} = 165$

Total volume of $a$ in $Z$ = $54 + 165 = 219$.

The answer is $219$.

Comment: "Your question is very basic" Not everyone will agree with that premise you just made. This question came from the Princeton Review guide for studying the GRE test and it is certainly not basic for me. That being said, I can't seem to downvote your answer, but I certainly would if I had enough rep.

Comment: If a question is in 'Princeton Review Guide' for GRE test, it doesn't mean it is an advanced question. This kind of problems we used to solve in 7th grade, to be precise.